# Regular Expression работа конструкции (?:x)

Tags: регулярные-выражения, c#

Доброго времени суток.
Согласно описанию на [MOZILLA DEVELOPER NETWORK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)...

> (?:x) - Matches x but does not remember the match.

Регулярному выражению `(?:{)"` в строке `{"Name":"Some text "/" some text"}` должна соответствовать первой кавычке, и только лишь кавычке, без открывающей фигурной скобки `"`, однако я получаю `{"`.

Либо я не правильно понимаю смысл конструкции (?:x) либо я не умею её готовить.

Также буду рад если кто подскажет как мне добиться нужного мне результата?

Answer (score 1):

Как Вы уже должны знать, каждой части выражения, которое заключено в круглые скобки, соответствует группа в результате (к которой можно обратиться как к массиву). Так вот фраза "does not remember the match." значит, что этой паре круглых скобок не будет соответствовать группа в результате.

То есть, в запросе `([1-9])([a-z]+)` - две группы, а в Вашем `(?:{)"` - нет ни одной.

Наиболее простое решение, которое я придумал - это написать так `(?:{)(")` - тогда  в результате будет одна группа, значение которой и будет "кавычка".

Comment: KoVadim, спасибо за ответ, но как я писал выше в моем случае запросу (?:{)" соответствует {", т.е. запоминается открывающаяся фигурная скобка и кавычка. http://jsfiddle.net/korchakmv/5YJr6/

Answer (score 1):

То что вы хотите сделать - это шаблон с заглядыванием назад (?<={)" (не поддерживается в javacript). А шаблон (?:{)" следует понимать так: соответствует строке {", при этом { не выделяется в отдельный элемент массива с результатом. Попробуйте сделать ({)" и увидите разницу.

Comment: В таком случае можете подсказать как мне заменить кавычку, которая стоит перед открывающей фигурной скобкой на что либо? У меня меняется и фигурная скобка тоже.

Comment: Заменяйте всю подстроку с фигурной скобкой вместе. У меня не грузится jsfiddle, не могу увидеть что конкретно вы хотите сделать.

Comment: На самом деле мне необходимо найти и заменить на \" в строке все кавычки кроме тех перед и после которых есть либо фигурная скобка либо двоеточие.